# Do I need to free memory of local vars in C?

Tags: c, memory

Just wondered what happens to the memory of local vars in a C program? I have a console application that runs 24hrs a day and want to make sure I free up memory safely.

Thanks
Pete

Comment: Don't describe your code. [Edit] your question and put some relevant code _there_. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: Basically you need to free explicitly only what has been allocated by `malloc`/ `calloc` and `realloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not use dynamic memory allocations, nothing to worry about.

Local variables are created on the stack.

Stack is a preallocated memory region, you can think this way: local variables are mapped to stack.

In some cases, it makes sense to nullify local variables for security reasons.

You can also run [Memory Sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141043/memory-sanitizer#34141338) to check if memory leaks exist in the program.

Comment: Theoretically you can fake dynamic memory allocations by abusing recursion. When you run out of memory it will then be in the form of a stack overflow.

Comment: @MSalters : I do not see how recursion can be described as faking dynamic memory allocation. A stack overflow is just a different and unrelated kind of memory management error.

Comment: @Clifford: The hypothetical `stackalloc` would take a continuation function as an argument, and never actually return to the caller.